# Javascript split after 20 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Given

```
string = 'Stackoverflow is awesome. It answers all my questions';
string = 'Stackoverflow. Q and A site';
```

I can get everything before the full-stop with `string.split('.')[0];`

But I only want to do this if full-stop appears after certain number of characters else return everything before the full-stop.

I properly need a regular expression to do this but am not sure how.

Comment: You _could_ use a regex, but there is absolutely no need for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a regex.

You can just do this:

```
function trimToDot(s) {
    var head = s.split('.')[0];
    return ( head.length > 20 ) ? head : s;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I changed my mind. The other answer returns an array that null if regex did not match. This means I will have to handle this. Which blows my whole shorter code idea. Your function handles this for me.

Comment: I will quickly agree that checking for null is no fun!

Answer (score 4):

`/^.{20,}?\./` should do it. The `^` tells it to start looking at the beginning of the search string, the first `.` means to match any charcter, the `{20,}` is a quantifier to mean "at least 20" and the `?` makes it match as few as possible (otherwise it will return everything up to the last dot). Finally the `\.` matches a literal dot.

Comment: Can you please elabrate, is this using split method?

Comment: Use `match`. The first return value will be an array with a single element, which is the substring you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method should be

```
var result = string.split('.')[0].length > 20 ? string.split('.')[0] : string;
```

Comment: This is better than using a regex (although both ways will work).

Comment: Even so I prefer the regex as it's shorter. I using node so performance is not as big of an issue as it would be in the browser.

Comment: @jamjam - It's your choice, but I've never understood why so many people think shorter code is better than readable code.

Comment: How is the regex not readable test.match(/^.{20,}?\./)[0] compared to the above is more readable, I think.

Comment: @jamjam -  I would argue that neither of those options are readable.  That's why I would prefer the approach used in my answer: do it the most straightforward way AND put it in a function so it can be re-used. Then you can add comments above the function and make it _super_ easy to understand and maintain...

Comment: Your answer is more readable but then I have to create extra function. Where with the regex am using a native function.

Comment: I consider creating a new function to be a good thing. It makes code easier to read and creates re-usable code.  Again, I've never understood why so many people consider this to be a bad thing.  Anywho... I'll stop trying to engage in a debate on coding style now.

Comment: Am of the opinion you should only create your own functions when the native ones can't do the job.

Comment: @jamjam - That doesn't make much sense.  Any function you create is just a collection of native functions.  Creating functions is how you write modularized code that is better organized and easier to read, maintain, and scale.  You sound like you may have been on one of the teams whose code I've inherited in the last few years ;)